# Select Fields with JOIN where column exists in distinct subquery with less fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

It's possible that this question has already been asked, but I can't seem to find my answer, so here goes:

I'm selecting 10 fields from a `JOIN` on two tables.  The result is about 1186 rows of data.  In these rows, several are duplicates for all intents and purposes, except for one unique field (`ClassId`).  I need this field, but it's keeping me from getting and what I have defined as "Unique".  For example, querying on only `Code`, `TeacherDescrip`, and `Term` yields 1120 records.

I was hoping to run this same query, but add a `WHERE` clause with a subquery that searched for a narrower set of fields, the three listed above to be exact, that excluded that unique field that was causing my "duplicates".  Of course, the error I received is below:

> "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

When i tried to use `EXISTS` in stead of `ClassScedule.Code IN` I still got back the full 1186.

here is my query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ClassId
      ,Code
      ,Section
      ,Course
      ,Students
      ,ClassStart
      ,TeacherDescrip
      ,AdTeacherID
      ,email
      ,Term
      ,Campus
  FROM ClassScedule
  JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = ClassScedule.AdTeacherID
  WHERE ClassStart BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-30'
        AND ClassScedule.Code IN 
              (SELECT DISTINCT ClassScedule.Code, TeacherDescrip, Termcode 
               FROM ClassScedule 
              WHERE ClassStart BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-30')
        AND TeacherDescrip IS NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY Instructor
```

Comment: So you have duplicates that only differ on the ClassId field. You want to remove the duplicates and keep the ClassId field. Now, from those "duplicates", what ClassId do you want to keep?

Comment: Great question, I'm flexible on that.  The purpose here is to survey teachers on a class they taught during a given term, but I don't want to survey them twice for teaching the same class two times in one term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can select one result for each distinct (Code, TeacherDescrip, Term) as follows:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       ClassId
      ,Code
      ,Section
      ,Course
      ,Students
      ,ClassStart
      ,TeacherDescrip
      ,AdTeacherID
      ,email
      ,Term
      ,Campus
  FROM ClassScedule
  JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = ClassScedule.AdTeacherID
  WHERE ClassStart BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-30'
  AND TeacherDescrip IS NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY Code, TeacherDescrip, Term
    ORDER BY ClassID DESC
  )
```

Among duplicate (Code, TeacherDescrip, Term) values, this query gives you the result with the smallest ClassID. If you want the largest instead, remove DESC.

Comment: wow...I HATE it when a solution comes along that works PERFECTLY but I have no idea why...I don't really understand the ROW_NUMBER() OVER syntax...but I'll research it!  Thanks Steve!

Comment: The ROW_NUMBER() expression provides distinguishing numbers 1, 2, 3... within each group of rows that have the same (Code, TeacherDescrip, Term) - these columns define the PARTITION - in DECReasing ClassId ORDER. Putting this into the main query's ORDER BY clause and selecting TOP (1) WITH TIES returns all the results that end up with the single lowest row number inside their partition (which is the number 1).

Comment: Absolutely.Brilliant.  Thanks for the explanation as well.  If you have any link that'll let me buy you a beer or a coffee...it's yours.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the dirty solution is:

```
 SELECT max(ClassId),
      ,Code ,Section ,Course ,Students ,ClassStart ,TeacherDescrip ,AdTeacherID
      ,email ,Term ,Campus
  FROM ClassScedule
  JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = ClassScedule.AdTeacherID
  WHERE ClassStart BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-30'
    AND TeacherDescrip IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY Code ,Section ,Course ,Students ,ClassStart ,TeacherDescrip
   ,AdTeacherID ,email ,Term ,Campus
  ORDER BY Instructor
```

This will get you the maximum ClassId of the "duplicates" values. It looks like the subquery is actually getting all class codes that are between those dates, but the outer query is already getting all those class codes so it is not necessary.

Comment: the key is to survey teachers on courses taught in a given term, without surveying them on the same course more than once, though they might teach that course in the daytime and at night in the same term...see what I mean?  

So the fact that the course has a unique ID is keeping me from doing this.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you can't return multiple columns in your subquery to do the comparison in the WHERE clause

```
              ClassScedule.Code IN 
              (SELECT DISTINCT ClassScedule.Code, TeacherDescrip, Termcode 
               FROM ClassScedule 
              WHERE ClassStart BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-30')
```

Does not help you anyway since you already get that from your main WHERE `clause`

Since the table has more than one `ClassId` for what you define as "unique", the only way to not get multiple rows returned would be to remove `ClassId` from the `SELECT`. Otherwise SQL Server has no way of knowing which `ClassId` you want.

IF you just want one `ClassId`, you can use the `MIN` or `MAX` `ClassId` and group on everything else.

Comment: curious, in doing this I'm still getting back all 1186 results.  is the MIN supposed to act like a grouping function here?

Comment: Yes, is it still giving multiple ClassIds where every other field is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a big group by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      min(ClassId) ClassId
     ,Code
     ,Section
     ,Course 
     ,Students
     ,ClassStart
     ,TeacherDescrip
     ,AdTeacherID
     ,email
     ,Term
     ,Campus
FROM ClassScedule
JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = ClassScedule.AdTeacherID
WHERE ClassStart BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-30'
  AND TeacherDescrip IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
      Code
     ,Section
     ,Course 
     ,Students
     ,ClassStart
     ,TeacherDescrip
     ,AdTeacherID
     ,email
     ,Term
     ,Campus
ORDER BY Instructor
```

The subquery is not needed. The columns may need to be tweaked a bit, without table aliases its not possible to tell what table they come from. I pick out the "first" ClassId, but you could use max() to pull out the "last" one.